# Merge two arrays with the same dimension based on a condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays with the same dimension:

```
a = [
[1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1], ]

b = [
[0, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 0, 2],
[0, 0, 0, 0], ]
```

I would like to create a new one, only changing the values where B is not 0 and is different than A. The result would be:

```
c = [
[1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 1],
[2, 0, 0, 2],
[1, 1, 1, 1], ]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You'd remove some ambiguity in the answers if you wrote those as arrays indstead of just nested lists.  Is the different from `a` an important part of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do assignment with boolean conditions:

```
a[b != 0] = b[b != 0]

a
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: What kind of obfuscation is this :D

Comment: @PetrL. Well I wouldn't consider this as obfuscation. It's pretty clear what it's doing. Assign values in `b` that's not zero to `a` at the same positions where `b` is not zero. It's concise and more importantly it's fast since it runs at the speed of C

Comment: is this something new?

Comment: @PetrL. I don't know what you consider as new. It's normal numpy operation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one that I find easy to parse:

```
>>> np.where(b,b,a)
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

This picks each value from either the third or second arguments based on whether the first argument is zero or not.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need numpy. Here is a solution you can actually read line by line:

```
a = [
[1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1], ]

b = [
[0, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 0, 2],
[0, 0, 0, 0], ]

c = a[:]
#I would like to create a new one, only changing the values where B is not 0 and is different than A. The result would be:

for lineindex,line in enumerate(a):
    for index,x in enumerate(line):
        if x != b[lineindex][index] and b[lineindex][index] != 0:
            c[lineindex][index] = b[lineindex][index]
print(c)
```

Comment: You are changing `a`.

Comment: @hpaulj Where sir?

Comment: Did you look at `a`?

Comment: @hpaulj I see, when I print a after I print c it is the same as c after the code. Which is VERY weird, since python for loops should not be async. Could you tell me what is happening?

Comment: @hpaulj I fixem it now. I thought list assignments are like integer assignments. Now it should work.